# Add string to new line in textarea element

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I want to insert string from a new row to my textarea HTML element.

I have this textarea element:

```
<textarea id="txtLogs" rows="13" cols="220"></textarea>
```

At some point I add text to the element above:

```
document.getElementById('txtLogs').value = 'tileloadStart...' + ' ' + layer.get('name') + ' ' + myTime;
```

And after some time again:

```
document.getElementById('txtLogs').value = 'tileloadEnd...' + ' ' + layer.get('name') + ' ' + myTime;
```

Every time I add a string to the textarea element it is added to the same row while I need the new string to be inserted to new row.

How do I change in my code to add a string to textarea element and display it in the new row?

Comment: `document.getElementById('txtLogs').value += ... +"\n"`

Answer (score 3):

You can add newline (`\n`) at the end of each line. Also, don't forget that we're appending the new lines so you have to use `+=`:

```js
 document.getElementById('txtLogs').value = 'first line\n';
 document.getElementById('txtLogs').value += 'second line\n';
 document.getElementById('txtLogs').value += 'third line\n';
```

```html
 <textarea id="txtLogs" rows="13" cols="220"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a return character aswell ( `\n` )

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = () => {
  let newRowString = "something on a new Row";
  let otherNewRowString = "Something else on a new row";


  let currentValue = document.getElementById('txtLogs').value;
  document.getElementById('txtLogs').value = currentValue + '\n' + 'tileloadStart...' + '\n' + newRowString + '\n' + otherNewRowString; 
};
```

```html
<textarea id="txtLogs"></textarea>

<button class="btn">add new row</button>
```

Comment: Because it's easier for me to create a complete example using JQuery and it does not affect what i'm trying to show OP.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your suggestion, thanks for the tip ! @mplungjan